# All-sides menu for android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am working on this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
(I think it is very popular)
I try to make an application that has 4 side menus. I checkout branch all-sides from that repository but it seem not work

```
SlidingMenu sl = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.slmenu);
        sl.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        sl.setMode(SlidingMode.LEFT);
        sl.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        sl.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sl.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        sl.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sl.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
        sl.setBehindScrollScale(.25f);

        sl.setContent(R.layout.dashboard_main);

        sl.setMenu(R.layout.dashboard_left);
        sl.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_left_shadow, SlidingMode.LEFT);

        sl.setMenu(R.layout.dashboard_right, SlidingMode.RIGHT);
        sl.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_right_shadow, SlidingMode.RIGHT);

        sl.setMenu(R.layout.dashboard_top, SlidingMode.TOP);
        sl.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_left_shadow, SlidingMode.TOP);

        sl.setMenu(R.layout.dashboard_bottom, SlidingMode.BOTTOM);
        sl.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_left_shadow, SlidingMode.BOTTOM);
```

Anyone know the way?